# Relying on file hash for data synchronisation across mobile and server

Tags: api-design, mobile, patterns-and-practices, server, client-server

Imagine a client-server app that lets user upload images/documents etc. to server and then lets users who have access, retrieve and view them later on their 
respective mobile devices.

So the flow is something like this:

- Creator (C) creates a message with n number of attachments.
- C uploads the files and message to server via REST API.
- Recipients R1, R2... Rn get notified about new content
- R1, R2, and other go in on their own times and fetch the message and attachments.
- Once downloaded, the mobile app doesn't request server the next time any of the recipients tries to view the attachments, it uses locally cached data.

Now the creator C already has the files (since it created them) and need not download them again. So when it gets a response from server like:

```js
{
  messageId: 123,
  attachments : [ { id: a1, ...}, {id: a2, ...}, {id: a3, ...} ]
}
```

However, it doesn't know which attachment is what (i.e. which one is `a1` and which one is `a2` and so on).

It just knows that message #123 has 3 attachments.

What would be a good way to figure this out? There are 2 approaches that come to my mind:

**Approach #1: use file hash**

- Calculate file hash (MD5 or SHA) and use that as a key on the mobile app.
- Server does the same and returns the hash as identifier instead of a generated id.

**Pros**:

- No extra metadata is needed for sync

**Cons**:

- Probably error prone - hash may not match due to OS or hash implementation differences
- Hashing will be slow for big files

**Approach #2: use a key**

- App generates an UUID and sends it to server as an identifier.
- Server stores it and returns the key with the response for syncing.

**Pros**

- Hash related errors are eliminated
- Hashing speed is not a concern since UUID generation is pretty quick and deterministic.

**Cons**

- And extra key is passed between app/server which has no other purpose.

Which one of these is preferable? Or maybe there is a 3rd option?

Comment: "Neither" might be a surprisingly valid option. The only reason I can think of for the "creator" downloading their own attachments would be to check if the attachment/download process is working successfully, in which case giving him any special caching treatment would actually be undesirable. Would users of your app have another reason?

Comment: I can think of few: a) Someone else decides to collaborate and adds one or more attachment. Creator sees that there are more attachments now but doesn't know which ones to request from server (w/o key synchronization it doesn't know which is which). b) Creator deletes one or more attachments from the message. Now instead of just passing the key/id to the server and asking it to delete, it has to send the remaining attachments again and server has to drop and re-insert again (not only an unnecessary blob op but if CDNs are involved, the deletion has to ripple out). There are more such scenarios

Comment: but suffice to say that for whatever reason, key synchro is needed (unless these issue can be mitigated thru some other means). Now if the message was non-editable, i.e. once created cannot be modified, then probably no snychro can be a viable option.